# SMTP with STARTTLS not working properly (postfix)

Tags: postfix

When I use *PHPMailer* to send mail through Postfix, I use the default config with these modifications:

```
# SMTP from other servers to yours
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/myletsencryptcert.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/myletsencryptcert.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/myletsencryptcert.crt
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database =
    btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
```

When I use this config, and run *PHPMailer*, it says connection failed, right after making the `STARTTLS` command. My *PHPMailer* config is

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'localhost';
    //$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'noreply@example.com';
    //$mail->Password   = 'passwordwhichissecretobviously';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port       = 25;
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

    $mail->setFrom("noreply@example.com", "Some person");
    $mail->addAddress("sperson@example.com");
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Web Development";
    $mail->Body    = "
Some random HTML message
";
    $mail->AltBody = "some normal message without HTML";
    $mail->XMailer    = "0"; 
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
    
    $mail->DKIM_domain = 'example.com';
    $mail->DKIM_private = '/right/path/to/dkimkey/which/works/properly/dkim.key';
    $mail->DKIM_selector = 'default';
    $mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
    $mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;
    $mail->DKIM_copyHeaderFields = false;
```

And even if I use telnet and do it, I get after running the STARTTLS command.

I found out that using this allows me to send the mail with *PHPMailer*:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    )
);
```

But I think that would be a security issue. How else can I make this work?

Comment: @anx, you mean, that I should remove the quotes?

Comment: @anx, you mean using the real domain name which the ssl cert has? Wow, that fixed it lol. I am so confused now. PLease post it as an answer. Oh my, I just wasted two whole days on this, with an headache. I am worth the downvotes I am going to get in this question.

Comment: But it still doesn't work with telnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Peer name verification only works if the peer name is known.**

Make it known, by configuring the server name as the `Host`.

```
// this is a name not mentioned in the cert
$mail->Host       = 'localhost';
// better: a full domain name
$mail->Host       = 'mx8.mydomain.example';
```

You (should) have a certificate for the name of your mail server - comparing that name in the certificate to `localhost` is not sufficient to determine the certificate is appropriate. Any mail client or test tool that wants to verify your certificate needs to know the name it should be comparing against.

**Nitpick:** Your SMTPSecure value contains the value of the const variable (the string `"tls"`) - use the name (`PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`) because the value itself does not explain what it means without looking into the documentation.

**About *telnet***: Using a simple test tool like *telnet* is a good choice for figuring out issues - but you cannot use `telnet` here - this program is (typically) not aware of TLS encryption. I like to use a utility included with *openssl* instead:

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname:25 -starttls smtp
```

(yes, it can even spell out `STARTTLS` for you and displays the connection parameters in a somewhat human-readable fashion)

Comment: Also, I realised the telnet thing doesn't work if I use `telnet chicjrajeevalochana.com 25`, and then run the starttls command, it just quits after I enter  the `MAIL FROM <mymail@chicjrajeevalochana.com>`

Comment: Naturally: telnet cannot handle TLS.

Comment: @EsaJokinen oh ok. Maybe thats probably the problem.

Comment: Anx, you provide absolutely great explanations. I feel dumb now (pun intended)... I feel even more dumb, because you edited my question and made it more readable

Comment: The goal here is to help both you asking the question and anyone else who might run into the same trouble later and read this, so you are absolutely welcome to edit both questions and answers that you believe can be improved (including but not limited to yours).

Comment: I am still feeling more dumber because someone upvoted my post. I thought they would downvote... Okay, let me stop making jokes... Thanks a lot for your solution. I cannot thank you enough... I couldn't even sleep yesterday night cuz of this. I wish I could give you a bounty of 50 rep, but I am unable to see the set a bounty button. I would give you 100 rep if this post was on stackoverflow, cuz i have 1000 rep there